# How to delete an item in sqlite using swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

I am trying to delete a primary key that the user can pass in. When i try to delete an item, nothing happens. Basically from the tableview i would get the indexpath.row to find out which item the user swiped left on and use that value to delete the row.

```
func DeleteRowDatabase(inputId : Int32) -> Bool
{
        var db: OpaquePointer? = nil
        var returnCode : Bool = true


          if sqlite3_open(self.databasePath, &db) == SQLITE_OK {

        print("Successfully opened connection to database at \(self.databasePath)")

            // step 16d - setup query - entries is the table name you created in step 0
            var deleteStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
            var deleteStatementString : String = "delete from entries where ID = ?"

            if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, deleteStatementString, -1, &deleteStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {


            sqlite3_bind_int(deleteStatement, inputId, inputId)
             sqlite3_close(db);

            }

        }

        return returnCode

    }




func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete {
            //books.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            print("INDEX PATH")
            print(indexPath.row)

            var x: Int32 = Int32(indexPath.row)

            x = x + 1

            let mainDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

            let returnCode : Bool = mainDelegate.DeleteRowDatabase(inputId: x)

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your main issue is that you never call `sqlite3_step` to actually execute the query.

But you also have other issues. You need to call `sqlite3_close` if you attempt to open the database whether the statement is prepared or not. You also need to call `sqlite3_finalize` on the prepared statement after you are done with it. And you are passing the wrong parameter value for the index in `sqlite3_bind_int`.

```
func DeleteRowDatabase(inputId : Int32) -> Bool {
    var db: OpaquePointer? = nil
    var returnCode : Bool = false

    if sqlite3_open(self.databasePath, &db) == SQLITE_OK {
        print("Successfully opened connection to database at \(self.databasePath)")

        // step 16d - setup query - entries is the table name you created in step 0
        var deleteStatement: OpaquePointer? = nil
        var deleteStatementString : String = "delete from entries where ID = ?"

        if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, deleteStatementString, -1, &deleteStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            sqlite3_bind_int(deleteStatement, 1, inputId)
            if sqlite3_step() == SQLITE3_DONE {
                returnCode = true
            }

            sqlite3_finalize(deleteStatement)
        }
    }

    sqlite3_close(db)

    return returnCode

}
```

Comment: @Rob Thanks for the heads up. I've done a lot with SQLite and never saw that little detail you quoted.

Comment: Me, too. I had been using SQLite forever without noticing this. It an edge case (tiny memory leak only when opening of database failed), so we don’t see it often in practice.

Answer (score 2):

Like rmaddy said,

1. You need to call `sqlite3_step` to actually perform the prepared statement.

Unrelated, but I’d also suggest:

2. Call `sqlite3_close` whether the routine succeeded or not. Even if `sqlite3_open` didn’t succeed, you must call `sqlite3_close`. As the [docs say](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html),

   > Whether or not an error occurs when it is opened, resources associated with the database connection handle should be released by passing it to `sqlite3_close()` when it is no longer required.
3. `sqlite3_finalize` the prepared statement.
4. I’d use `guard` statements to avoid towers of nested `if` statements.
5. Check the return code of `sqlite3_bind_xxx`, too.
6. I’d call `sqlite3_changes` to actually confirm whether any rows were deleted or not.
7. I’d start my method names with lower case letters.

Thus:

```
func deleteRowDatabase(inputId: Int32) -> Bool {
    var db: OpaquePointer?
    
    defer { sqlite3_close(db) }
    guard sqlite3_open(databasePath, &db) == SQLITE_OK else {
        return false
    }
        
    print("Successfully opened connection to database at \(self.databasePath)")
        
    // step 16d - setup query - entries is the table name you created in step 0
    var statement: OpaquePointer?
    let sql = "DELETE FROM entries WHERE id = ?"
        
    guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
        return false
    }
    
    defer { sqlite3_finalize(statement) }
            
    guard sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, inputId) == SQLITE_OK else {
        return false
    }

    guard sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE else {
        return false
    }
    
    guard sqlite3_changes(db) == 1 else {
        return false
    }

    return true
}
```

---

I’d also suggest:

8. This pattern of opening and closing the database for every SQL statement is a bit inefficient. I’d open the database once and leave it at that.
9. I worry about assuming that the `ID` for a row in the table corresponds to `indexPath.row`. What happens if you have 10 records and delete the first one. You then restart the app and there’s now 9 records, but now first row in table corresponds to ID of 2. I’d suggest building an array of ID values when you read in the table, and use those values for subsequent operations, rather than assuming the `ID` is equal to  `indexPath.row + 1`.

Comment: FWIW, I’d suggest getting out of the business of writing hairy SQLite code like this. There are tons of SQLite wrappers out there. Or if you want to wrap your own, you could start with something like https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/515bbfc751dd97f5d0745dceee32d3b4.